# WLAN Problems at 16.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

There is a problem with my brand new Notebook "Terra 360-11", using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTE or 16.10 (with Windows 10 all features are in function):

WLAN (WPA personal, 80.211 b/g/n) is recognized by the network-manager, but if you edit the password to connect, system asks you over and over again for the password and don't connect (there are only use standard digits and numbers without ä-ö-ü etc).
WLAN-Chip:
Broadcom BCM4356 14e4:43ec (rev.2)

I have tried many options to start WLAN, described in the various Ubuntu help sites, newest firmware etc., but no success.

I do not want to work with windows. Is there a chance to use Ubuntu?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43ec] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2217]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

Comment: Your name sounds German. If you speak German, i suggest you read this: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)